# Trying to convert a dataframe to a dictionary in Python-Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I've got the following dataframe

```
      Firm      Item  Cost
0   Firm A     Books  0.55
1   Firm A   Pencils  0.60
2   Firm B     Books  0.45
3   Firm B   Pencils  0.35
```

and I would like to convert it into the following dictionary

```
{('Firm A', 'Books'): 0.55, ('Firm A', 'Pencils'): 0.6, ('Firm B', 'Books'): 0.45, ('Firm B', 'Pencils'): 0.35}
```

I tried with

```
costs_dictionary = df.set_index('Firm','Item').to_dict()
```

But with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add list to [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and select column `Cost` before `to_dict`:

```
costs_dictionary = df.set_index(['Firm','Item'])['Cost'].to_dict()
print (costs_dictionary)
{('Firm A', 'Books'): 0.55, ('Firm A', 'Pencils'): 0.6, 
 ('Firm B', 'Books'): 0.45, ('Firm B', 'Pencils'): 0.35}
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael. You are very right, I forgot to select the column 'Cost'! :-)